# How can Initialize My AutoMapper with my configs

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Here is My Code :

```
My Initializer Class
    public class Initializer : IMapInitializer
    {
        IMapInitializer _mapInitializer;
        public Initializer(IMapInitializer mapInitializer)
        {
            _mapInitializer = mapInitializer;
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(config =>
            {
                config.CreateMap<OrderMain, OrderDO>().ReverseMap();
                //Others
                  .....
            });
        }

    }
```

Here is IMapInitializer

```
public interface IMapInitializer
{
    void Initialize();
}
```

> What can i do in Startup.cs ? I have  tried
>
> ```
>  service.AddTransient()
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call Mapper.Initialize once in your Startup.Configure method, there's no need to involve the DI container:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(c =>
    {
        c.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>();
        c.CreateMap<SomethingElse, SomethingElseDto>();
        //etc...
    });

    //snip...
}
```

Your mappings will then be available whenever you call map:

```
var dto = Mapper.Map<OrderDto>(myOrder);
```

---

### Edit

So if you do want to initialise your mappings via a class registered in the DI container, you'd do the following:

Define your interface (exactly as you have already):

```
public interface IMapInitializer
{
    void Initialize();
}
```

Implement it, you just need the implementation of the interface and you'd only need to include other interfaces in the constructor if you wanted to inject different dependencies into your Initializer class (e.g. a logger which would also need registering with the DI container):

```
public class Initializer : IMapInitializer
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<OrderMain, OrderDTO>().ReverseMap();
            //Others
        });
    }
}
```

Then register this in the DI container with either AddTransient (your class will be created whenever it's needed), AddScoped (created once per request) or AddSingleton (once per the lifetime of the app). I'm using scoped here as you'll likely just want to use this once anyway as once you've created your mappings they'll be available for the life of your app anyway:

```
services.AddScoped<IMapInitializer, Initializer>();
```

Now you can use the DI container to inject the above into whatever requires it, e.g. into a controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IMapInitializer _initializer = null;

    public MyController(IMapInitializer initializer)
    {
        _initializer = initializer ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(initializer));
    }

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        //initialize - although once you've done this you don't need to do so again!
        initializer.Initialize();

        //use mappings...
    }
}
```

Comment: I want write Mapper.Initialize Method to another class. And  i want call from in DI container

Comment: OK, but why? It's relatively expensive to call multiple times, why not just do it once at startup? I can edit my answer if you really want to do it that way but it seems like more effort than it's worth tbh.

Comment: I want to write initializer to another class but i call di conteiner

Answer (score 0):

I create static initializer will be called from ConfigureServices

```
 public static class MapperInitializer
{
    public static void MapperConfiguration()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            //Configs..
        });
    }
}
```

> I do like this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       MapperInitializer.MapperConfiguration();
    }
```

Completed. Thanks